# Get weekday (day of week) with ngb datepicker

Tags: angular, datepicker, dayofweek

I am using Bootstrap 4 and Angular 2 and ngb.

With the [datepicker](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/datepicker/api) from ngb the user selects a date and i can easily get the day, the month and the year, becaue of the date structure:

```
Model: {
"year": 2017,
"month": 10,
"day": 25
}
```

But i also need the day of the week. I coundn't find any information about this in the api. Is it possible or what would be a good way to get the weekday?

What i did so far is:

```
    this.date = this.datepicked.year + "-" + this.datepicked.month + "-" + this.datepicked.day;
    let date = new Date(this.date);
    this.day_of_week = date.getDay();
```

Is there a more elegant solution (supported by ngb)?

Greetings,
Steffi

Comment: Take a look at MomentJS lib -  https://momentjs.com/  , it gives you solution for all date manipulations and dates functionality

Comment: new Date(this.datepicked.year,this.datepicked.month-1,this.datepicked.day).getDay() ?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know this specific library but according to the docs you can use:

```
getWeekdayShortName()
```

If that's not working then you can use [momentjs](https://momentjs.com/docs/):

```
var date = moment("2015-07-02");
var dow = date.day();
```

[momentjs](https://momentjs.com/docs/) has many great useful functions.